# Regular Expression works in 2 different web-evaluators but not in code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm currently working on a forum and wanted to use regular expressions to find tables in posts and convert them to BB-Code. I used a web-evaluator (http://regexr.com) and worked out a regular expression.

```
/^(\[table\]\s*)^((?:[^\|\r\n]+[\|\n])+)^(\[\/table\])$/m
```

It is used to detect tables of the form:

```
[table]
abc|def|gih
123|456|789
[/table]
```

But when I transfer this text to my script via POST and a `<textarea>`, use `preg_match_all` on it with that pattern and `var_dump` the result I only get empty arrays. Logically, the replace functions don't work either.

```
preg_match_all("/^(\[table\]\s*)^((?:[^\|\r\n]+[\|\n])+)^(\[\/table\])$/m", $_POST['test_string'], $tmp);
var_dump($tmp);
```

This outputs

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } [3]=> array(0) { } }
```

PS: I know that regexr.com is JS-based, so I tried a php-based [one](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) where it worked perfectly, too.

Edit: Added Codesample

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: As far as I know, any language requires escaping special character in strings. So at first try to replace "\" with "\\". E.g. "\n" means "new line" and "\\" means single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes of the regular expression for usage in PHP strings:

```
$pattern = "/^(\\[table\\]\\s*)^((?:[^\\|\\r\\n]+[\\|\\n])+)^(\\[\\/table\\])$/m";
```

If you'd like to keep using a site like regexr, try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) instead. After writing a regular expression, you can click on `Tools > code generator` and it will show you code that is ready for use in PHP.

Comment: Looks good but the problem now is that this only works when I directly define a variable with the string inside the php script. When I try it on the string passed to my script via POST and a textarea it doesn't work anymore (likely doesn't detect the linebreaks for what reason ever). 
`array(4) { [0]=> string(40) "[table] abc|def|gih 123|456|789 [/table]" [1]=> string(8) "[table] " [2]=> string(24) "abc|def|gih 123|456|789 " [3]=> string(8) "[/table]" } string(40) "[table] abc|def|gih 123|456|789 [/table]"
array(0) { } string(43) "[table] abc|def|gih 123|456|789 [/table]"`
1 in script, 2 POST

Comment: Edit: worked, but I first had to explode the input on new lines, trim it and then implode it back with linefeed as glue.

Comment: Seems like you had trailing whitespace in the input. Your regex pattern is relatively strict. I'd rather fix the regex than work around it using explode/trim/implode. Maybe try adding a `\s*` after the last `[\/table\]`.

Comment: I did do that. Thanks.